# Trouble understanding how for loops work in java

Tags: java, for-loop

I'm new at java and I have to write a code for a multiplication table. I have the multiplication working for a square table but I need it to work for a reverse triangle. What do I need to add to the code to make it print like this following examples?

```
/*What I have:
1   2   3   4
2   4   6   8
3   6   9   12
4   8   12  16

What I want:
1  2  3  4
   4  6  8
      9  12
         16
*/
import java.util.Scanner;

public class question3{
  public static void main(String[] args){

    System.out.print("Enter an integer between 1 and 10: ");
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    int value = input.nextInt();

    if(value < 0 || value > 10){
        while(value < 0 || value > 10){
        System.out.print("Enter an integer between 1 and 10: ");

        value = input.nextInt();

            if(value <= 10){
                for(int x=1; x <= value; x++){

                    System.out.println();
                    for(int y=1; y<= value; y++){

                        int z=x*y;
                        System.out.printf(z + "\t");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    else if (value <=10 && value >=0){
        for(int x=1; x <= value; x++){

            System.out.println();
            for(int y=1; y<= value; y++){

                int z=x*y;
                System.out.printf(z + "\t");
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println();
  }
}
```

Comment: So what is your question?  What have you tried?  What does your debugger say?  What errors are you getting?  What is incorrect?  What have you tried to fix what is incorrect?  You have pasted an image and asked us to fix your code for you with little to go on which Stack Overflow does not do.

Comment: OK, now that you've told us what you want to do, please [edit] your question and add, you know, a question to it.  We have no way to know what sort of trouble you're having *if you don't tell us what it is*.

Comment: Hi Alex, your question is not really about java, it's more about how do I get the effect that I want. Hint: You have to think through the loops and figure out how to skip over the bits on the lower triangle. :P also you have to simplify your if statements

Answer (score 0):

from the given information i assume that you want to make a table which display values

```
  /* 1  2  3  4
        4  6  8
           9  12
              16  */
```

here is the simple code which i have written , it also display the same table which you want.

```
   int row,column  ;
   column = row = 4;

   String space = " ";
   for(int i=0;i<row;++i)
    {
        for(int x=0;x<2*i;++x )
         {
               System.out.print(space);
          }
        for(int y=1; y<=column; ++y)
          {
              System.out.print(space);
              System.out.print((y+i)*(i+1));
           }
        column = column -1;
        System.out.println();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks guys for your answers and support. Just a noob trying to figure this out

Comment: I have and it helped me greatly. Thank you